# Is it memory inefficient to instantiate classes in a getter method? What OOP design prevents this?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a getter method that instantiates classes from deserialized data. I suspect this is a terribly inefficient way of doing things

```
class Container {
  get content() {
    let contentList = []
    for (let c of this._content) { // this._content is an array of objects
      contentList.push(new ContentTypes[c.type](c)) //ContentTypes is a mapping between type names and classes
    }
    return contentList
  }
}
```

What's the appropriate design pattern in OOP land?

Comment: "*What's the appropriate design pattern in OOP land?*" what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to prevent the getter function from initializing a new object every call.

Comment: Then just cache them and return from cache. But my question was broader - what is your code trying to do? You don't apply a design pattern on just lines of code but on a *problem*. Perhaps you need a factory pattern, perhaps not. I can't really tell.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right! Clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the code is in a getter or a method, the efficiency doesn't change. But what changes is the *expectation* of the person writing code using your class.

I don't expect accessing a property on an object to incur much overhead. So when using an instance of `Container`, if I see a `contents` property, I'm not going to expect it to do a lot of work. Yours does (a bit).

I would either:

1. Keep a copy of what you return (making what you return immutable) and only discard it when the things it relies on change, or
2. Make it a method (explicitly).

*(Or I might do both.)*

I expect method calls to incur more overhead than property accesses. I don't know if there's a specific OOP principle one can cite about that, but that's my view from experience (for what it may or may not be worth).

**But**, note that there are counterexamples out in the wild. A famous and directly applicable one is the `innerHTML` property of DOM elements, which is an accessor property that does a fair bit of work when you use it.

Here's an example of returning an immutable thing you keep and re-return, but invalidate when its underlying data changes:

```
class Container {
    constructor() {
        this._content = [];
        this._exposedContent = null;
    }

    addContent(content) {
        this._content.push(content);
        this._exposedContent = null; // Invalidating the cached copy if any
    }

    get content() {
        // Do we have a cached copy?
        if (!this._exposedContent) {
            // No, create it
            this._exposedContent = this._content.map(
                c => Object.freeze(new ContentTypes[c.type](c))
            );
        }
        return this._exposedContent;
    }
}
```

(You might also expire the copy after a period of time.)

But it's a judgement call whether it's worth the memory overhead and complexity vs. what your code actually in your `content` accessor. My default position would be to use a method instead (`getContent` or similar) and not cache, but it's a judgement call.